# Разпознавание изображений на C#

Tags: c#, алгоритм, изображения

У меня есть задание:

> В наборе двумерных фигур есть
> треугольники, прямоугольники,
> восьмиугольники, ромбы, окружности и
> эллипсы. Распознать треугольники и
> прямоугольники

Как реализовать такое на C#?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть замечательная библиотека по распознаванию, обработке (и многое другое) изображений - [OpenCV](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenCV). По ссылке в разделе `Ссылки` найдете библиотеки для использования в C#. Но, упрощу вам задачу, вот [ссылка](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Shape_(Triangle,_Rectangle,_Circle,_Line)_Detection_in_CSharp) где приводится решение, из официальных примеров, по распознаванию треугольника и квадрата.

Comment: Спасибо Большое, хоть понял куда копать, в какую сторону!!!

Comment: Да, EmguCV работает отлично. Вот ссылка на саму либу: http://sourceforge.net/projects/emgucv/